# mock nodemailer.createTransport.sendMail with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, nodemailer

I have some code which uses the [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) module.

In the router (router.js), I have

```
const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport(emailArgs);
```

Then inside the route (`/login`) I have:

```
...
return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

I'm trying to test this route using the `jest` testing framework. I'm having some trouble mocking out the call to `sendMail`. I read [this nice blogpost](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c) about how to use jest mocking, but I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMail' of undefined

And indeed when I check the value of `transporter` it's undefined.

Here is my testing code (which doesn't work):

```
import request from "supertest";
import router from "./router";

jest.mock("nodemailer");

describe("", () => {
...

    test("", async () => {
        // 1 - 200 status code; 2 - check email was sent
        expect.assertions(2);

        const response = await request(router)
            .post("/login")
            // global variable
            .send({ "email": email })
            .set("Accept", "application/json")
            .expect("Content-Type", /json/);

        // should complete successfully
        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        // TODO not sure how to express the expect statement here
    });
});
```

So my question is **how do I mock out a method of an instance of a class which is returned by a module**?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and found a solution. Here is what I've discovered:

With `jest.mock("nodemailer");` you tell jest to replace `nodemailer` with an auto-mock. This means every property of `nodemailer` is replaced with an empty mock function (similar to `jest.fn()`).

That is the reason why you get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendMail' of undefined`. 
In order to have something useful, you have to define the mock function of `nodemailer.createTransport`.

In our case we wan't to have an object with a property `sendMail`. We could do this with `nodemailer.createTransport.mockReturnValue({"sendMail": jest.fn()});`. Since you may want to test if `sendMail` was called, it is a good idea to create that mock function before hand.

Here is a complete example of your testing code:

```
import request from "supertest";
import router from "./router";

const sendMailMock = jest.fn(); // this will return undefined if .sendMail() is called

// In order to return a specific value you can use this instead
// const sendMailMock = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(/* Whatever you would expect as return value */);

jest.mock("nodemailer");

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer"); //doesn't work with import. idk why
nodemailer.createTransport.mockReturnValue({"sendMail": sendMailMock});

beforeEach( () => {
    sendMailMock.mockClear();
    nodemailer.createTransport.mockClear();
});

describe("", () => {
...

    test("", async () => {
        // 1 - 200 status code; 2 - check email was sent
        expect.assertions(2);

        const response = await request(router)
            .post("/login")
            // global variable
            .send({ "email": email })
            .set("Accept", "application/json")
            .expect("Content-Type", /json/);

        // should complete successfully
        expect(response.status).toBe(200);

        // TODO not sure how to express the expect statement here
        expect(sendMailMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: for anyone else looking at this trying to get it to work. the above should have a mockReturnValue that reads:

`nodemailer.createTransport.mockReturnValue({sendMail: sendMailMock});` (without quotes)

Comment: To get it to work with ES6 module you need to use import * as nodemailer from "nodemailer". Ensure you do this in both the test and the subject file.

Comment: if you are facing timeout issue the 
I have fixed that with this change
`const sendMailMock = jest.fn((mailOptions, callback) => callback());`

Answer (score 10):

To mock nodemailer module I do

```
jest.mock('nodemailer', () => ({
  createTransport: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    sendMail: jest.fn().mockReturnValue((mailoptions, callback) => {})
  })
}));
```

works like a charm

you can also define a mocked function if you need to evaluate `.toBeCalledWith()` etc:

```
const sendMailMock = jest.fn()
jest.mock('nodemailer', () => ({
  createTransport: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    sendMail: sendMailMock,
  })),
}))
```

Comment: Is there a way to get to the mocks from there? (eg. to use toHaveBeenCalled() on that sendMail there?)

Comment: I keep getting the error `TypeError: transporter.use is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

well I still wanted my mailer to work and returning undefined was not working, so I had to change sendMailMock to this:

```js
const sendMailMock = jest.fn((mailOptions, callback) => callback());
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

1. Create a mock file at the directory **mocks**/nodemailer.js (See [Jest Manual Mock for reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks))
2. Add the following code to the file. The createTransport method needs to return a response that has a method sendMail for it to work. So see the code used below

```js
class CreateTransportClass {
  sendMail(){
    //console.log("mocked mailer");
  }
}
const createTransport = ()=>{
  return new CreateTransportClass()
}


module.exports = {
  createTransport
}
```

3. In the jest config file (jest.config.js) add the file path to the testPathIgnorePatterns like this:

```js
{

    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/__mocks__/nodemailer.js"],
}
```

This should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To mock nodemailer package you can use following code with jest SpyOn method:

```
jest.spyOn( nodemailer, 'createTransport' ).mockReturnValue( {
                createTransport: jest.fn().mockReturnValue( {
                    sendMail: jest.fn().mockReturnValue( ( mailoptions, callback ) => { } )
                } ),
            } as any );
```